# Can JGraphX be used "headless"?

Tags: java, headless, jgraphx

It's not obvious from looking at the documentation for JGraphX whether one can use it just perform layout or nodes and edges without there being a rendering environment. Can it be used "headless"?

Answer (score 0):

No, almost every routine of JGraphX uses classes from `java.awt` package.